# How do I import service references to Unity3D?

Tags: unity, .net, dll, plugin

I'm attempting access a service reference in Unity. I need two: the SOAP framework and a separate service called `ContentVault`.

The respective service URL's are:

- SOAP: http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc
- `ContentVault`: http://ioun.wizards.com/ContentVault.svc

Both services import fine in to Visual Studio. I've tried everything I can think of but they won't work with Unity. I just get various errors (changing depending on which solution I'm trying out).

I've attempted using `svcutil` to export the services as external scripts, but all I got was a bunch of using errors. I've tried converting the code to work with .NET 2.0 to no avail, I've even tried making the services in to .DLL's to no success.

How could get these services working with Unity?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting NotImplementedException exceptions, then you are likely out of luck.

Unity uses Mono, and, sadly, Mono is not a full implementation of the .net framework.

There are many features of .net that have not been added to Mono yet.

BasicHttpBinding is one of those features that has not been added.

I've had some limited success with named pipe bindings and I know of others that have successfully used tcp/ip bindings.

Much of WCF doesn't work with Unity, which is a huge let-down!

For more info on what is implemented from System.ServiceModel and what isn't, you could check this page:

http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.ServiceModel

Keep in mind, for this to ever get implemented, it would first have to be added to Mono and then Unity would have to adopt the new version of Mono.